# Tinymce Editor not coming up on Croogo on server

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, admin, croogo

I am new to Croogo. I have created few pages on my local server. I was able to use the editor there but when I uploaded the files on server I can't find any editor attached, I can only see few html tags with the text.

Is it something to do with this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /hermes/bosoraweb081/b2606/sl.onpointsaliency/public_html/app/Plugin/Tinymce/webroot/js/tiny_mce.js on line 1

Comment: what is your `<script>` statement to connect `tiny_mce.js`?

Comment: The message you are getting is a __PHP__ error message. So the `tiny_mce.js` file gets parsed by PHP – I’m not sure if that’s supposed to happen (doubt it), or happens by accident here because your server is configured to parse files ending in `.js` as PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cache files under /app/tmp, and also delete your browser cache since CakePHP sets cache for plugin assets, and try re-loading the page.